# Edit PATH variable content

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, python, macos

When I type `python3` on my zsh terminal, Python 3.9 gets launched:

```
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Since `which python3` output is:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

which means that `python3` executable is located there.

I want to switch from Python 3.9 to Python 3.11 when using terminal. I have installed Python 3.11 and it is located at:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
```

This is `echo $PATH` output:

```
/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

In order to launch Python 3.11 instead of Python 3.9 when typing `python3` (or `python`, actually) on my terminal, I think I should

- Insert on the top of `PATH` variable Python 3.11 executable, that is `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH`. This actually works since `echo $PATH` now prints `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin` on top of `PATH` variable; or
- Edit `PATH` variable deleting both `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin` while leaving `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin`.

Note that `cat ~/.zshrc` prints:

```
# python aliases
alias python="python3"
alias pip="pip3"

# adb
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

# English
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

What should I do? Am I supposed to edit `~/.zshrc` file and append `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH` or am I supposed to delete `3.9` and `3.10` from `PATH` variable, or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, the `$path` array is tied to the `$PATH` variable.

You can make sure the elements are unique by doing `typeset -U path`.

Then you can insert or move a directory to the front with:

```
path[1,0]=( /that/dir )
```

To remove entries that match a pattern, you can do:

```
path=( ${path:#pattern} )
```

So here, combined together, that could be:

```
typeset -U path 
path=( ${path:#/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.<0-10>/bin} )
path[1,0]=( /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin )
```

Beware that if you update `$PATH`, that will affect scripts written with a:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

shebangs, but if scripts need a particular version of python, they probably would have a

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.9
```

she-bang, or use one of the many ways to navigate around the jolly mess that python versioning is.

Comment: That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since an alias is already set. Have you tried to source it?

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Failing that, a second approach could be to set up a symlink on Python 3.9 that points to Python 3.11

Comment: My question is about a proper way to achieve my goal, indeed